# FastRoute - latest version, am I using the right one?

Tags: php, url-routing, fastroute

I'm introducing PHP routing into my website, I'm using FastRoute as it seems to be popular but the latest release on gitHub is 2018 (v1.3.0) but there are changes as recent as 3 weeks ago, what am I missing?

I'm using PHP 8.2.

Comment: Maybe they've been working on the next version for a while. Sometimes if code is good and does everything it's supposed to, you don't need to update it all that often. They seem to have someone asking if they can tag a 1.4 though - see https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute/issues/259 . So maybe they've just got bad at marking things as releases. Maybe see what you actually get if you install it via composer. If still in doubt, contact the maintainer about what they would consider to be a stable version you can use.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson . I'm using composer and my understanding is that it will only download stable versions. So as you say I would need to wait for a release.